# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when selecting view

Tags: oracle, view

When I try to execute a view that includes tables from different schemas an ORA-001031 Insufficient privileges is thrown.  These tables have execute permission for the schema where the view was created.  If I execute the view's SQL Statement it works.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the table owner you need to grant SELECT access on the underlying tables to the user you are running the SELECT statement as.

```
grant SELECT on TABLE_NAME to READ_USERNAME;
```

Answer (score 38):

Finally I got it to work.  Steve's answer is right but not for all cases.  It fails when that view is being executed from a third schema.  For that to work you have to add the grant option:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON [TABLE_NAME] TO [READ_USERNAME] WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

That way, `[READ_USERNAME]` can also grant select privilege over the view to another schema

Comment: What if dba grants the priviledge. I am not getting this work although user is granted privilege by dba to views created and underlying tables.

Answer (score 6):

Q.  When is the  "with grant option"  required ?

A. when you have a view executed from a third schema.

Example:
    schema  DSDSW  has a  view called view_name

```
a) that view selects from a table in another schema  (FDR.balance)
b) a third shema  X_WORK  tries to select  from that view
```

Typical grants:
    grant select on  dsdw.view_name   to  dsdw_select_role;
    grant  dsdw_select_role to  fdr;

But:   fdr gets
    select count(*) from  dsdw.view_name;
     ERROR at line 1:
     ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

issue the grant:

```
grant select on fdr.balance to dsdw with grant option;
```

now fdr:
    select count(*) from dsdw.view_name;
         5 rows

Answer (score 4):

Let me make a recap.

When you build a view containing object of different owners, those other owners have to grant "with grant option" to the owner of the view.  So, the view owner can grant to other users or schemas....

Example:
User_a is the owner of a table called mine_a
User_b is the owner of a table called yours_b

Let's say user_b wants to create a view with a join of mine_a and yours_b

For the view to work fine, user_a has to give "grant select on mine_a to user_b with grant option"

Then user_b can grant select on that view to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

If the view is accessed via a stored procedure, the execute grant is insufficient to access the view.  You must grant select explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If the view is accessed via a stored procedure, the execute grant is insufficient to access the view. You must grant select explicitly.

simply type this

grant all on  to public;

Answer (score 1):

To use a view, the user must have the appropriate privileges but only for the view itself, not its underlying objects. However, if access privileges for the underlying objects of the view are removed, then the user no longer has access. This behavior occurs because the security domain that is used when a user queries the view is that of the definer of the view. If the privileges on the underlying objects are revoked from the view's definer, then the view becomes invalid, and no one can use the view. Therefore, even if a user has been granted access to the view, the user may not be able to use the view if the definer's rights have been revoked from the view's underlying objects.

Oracle Documentation
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm#DBSEG98017

Answer (score 0):

you may also create view with schema name
for example  **create or replace view schema_name.view_name as select..**

Comment: Hi. Please add in details with your answer.