# ORA-01031 Insufficient privileges while CREATING a VIEW?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle11g

When I try to create a view that including different tables I'm getting the following error:
Error at Line 1:
ORA-01031 Insufficient privileges.

Could anyone tell me what could be the problem. I tried following the another stackoverflow post mentioned here but it's pertaining to 
different schemas.

[ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when selecting view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140643/ora-01031-insufficient-privileges-when-selecting-view)

Please let me know as I'm new here.

My Query is as follows:

ORiginal Question:Create a view to select employee ID, employee name, hire date, and department number.

MY SOLUTION:

```
CREATE VIEW SIMPVIEW AS
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, HIREDATE,DEPTNO
FROM EMP;
```

Comment: Do you have the `create view` privilege? Do you own the `emp` table, or are you accessing it in another schema (e.g. the `HR` sample schema)? If it's in another schema, do you have the `select` priv against it through a role or directly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I'm running queries on my computer with Oracle 11g installed. So, I'm my own DBA but since I'm new I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: And yes, I have created emp table.

Comment: Apparently the user you are using doesn't have the `create view` privilege. You need to grant that the same way you granted the `create table` privilege. Check the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9013.htm#i2155015

Comment: Actually, I didn't grant any privilege to     create table privilege. Also, I'm logged in as an administrator on my computer.

Comment: Who you are logged in as on your *computer* isn't relevant. This is about the user you're connected as in the database, e.g. `SCOTT` if you're playing with default schemas, and what roles and privileges that user has been granted. Hopefully you are not using a built-in account like `SYS`...

Comment: Got it. I'm logged in as SCOTT (Als checked via "sho user " SQL command). The emp, dept tables are created by me with my own data.There is nothing default thing with which I'm working.

Comment: Do I need to follow the steps mentioned in the link below?

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=641397

But I'm wondering what should I write in place of the query written over there which is 

Grant create snapshot, create table, create view to <username>; 

What would be the query in my case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Then probably you may not have the privileges to perform the `CREATE VIEW` command in your database schema... Log in into SYSDBA account and issue the command

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO <dbusername>;
```

Here `<dbusername>` should be replaced with the name of the user you want to give access to the `CREATE VIEW` command.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if your user has `VIEW` creation privileges using `select * from session_privs`.

Note that to be able to create a view, the user that is creating it needs to have been granted `SELECT` privileges on all the objects being used, as well as the mentioned `CREATE VIEW` privilege. You can also check that by querying to `USER_TAB_PRIVS` with the user getting the error.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error, and the solution was to `grant select WITH GRANT OPTION`
to a table from another schema that was included in the view.

Answer (score 2):

when I wanted to execute the above query in sql developer I faced issues as I did not have enough privileges to create a view or other oracle object schema such as trigger, packages, procedures etc. I found the error to i.e. “Error at Line 1: ORA-01031 Insufficient privileges”. so, I needed the all privileges to practice all these queries and programs. I took the following steps in order to solve my problem:

1. As I logged in as a user name ‘scott’, so my name is ‘scott’ not ‘Dhruv’. My ambition was to grant all the privileges to me i.e. to the user ‘scott’.
2. For that, I need to enter in the database as a DBA. Now, question is! How to log in as DBA. For this, I opened command prompt and I logged in the database as sysdba by following the below steps:

a)  In window run, I typed cmd to open command prompt. I typed: sqlplus /nolog which means that I logged in without providing required credentials.
b)  I authenticated myself for my underlying O/S and entered in database as DBA. For that, I typed in command prompt: connect / as sysdba;
c)  I evaluated who is the DBA user in my database if exists. For that I typed: select name from V$database; 
d)  Here we go after this command. I finally granted myself (scott) to create view in sql developer by typing the command: grant create view to scott;
e)  Finally, I granted myself all the privileges by typing: grant all privileges to scott;

Snapshot of command prompt: I have attached.

Finally, I executed and created my view: I have attached

Comment: There's nothing attached

Comment: @Dhruv Can you attach your attachment?

Comment: Even though this is a few years old, I was in the exact same situation as @Dhruv. The steps listed above are exactly what helped me.

Answer (score 0):

1. At first You need to give the user authentication so you need to know who dba in normal the system give this authentication so make `conn system/ *password*`
2. give grand or authentication  by put `grant create view to *DataBaseUsername*;`
3. make the connection to your user and apply your command

Answer (score -2):

You have to give select any table privilege to the user. Then the view will compile successfully. No need to explicitly grant select to the user to all the objects.