# User can view table from other user ORACLEDB

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I created a table called `products` from a user called `john`.  I want a user called `doe` to have permission to view that table and another user called `lorem` to be able to delete, insert, select, and update in this table. How can I do that? What roles and privileges do I need to set?

PD: someone told me that I have to do this with a:

```
CREATE VIEW view_products
as
SELECT * FROM products;
```

Is this right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when selecting view] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/140665/1563878). Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/189496/1563878) too. If you can, post the oracle error code.

Comment: You do not need a view.  Read up on the GRANT statement.

Comment: I do this 'GRANT SELECT ON COCO.PRODUCTOS TO "ZETA" WITH GRANT OPTION' but with _zeta_ i can view the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GRANT statement:

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on products to lorem;

grant select on products  to doe;
```

If you plan on allowing multiple, different users access, then you may want to create a ROLE, assign users to the specific roles, then grant access to the roles instead of a individual user.  That way, if you add more users in the future, you just have to assign them the proper role, and not mess with the table rights again.  Easier to manage.

To use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW view_products
as
SELECT * FROM products;


grant select, insert, update, delete on view_products to lorem;
grant select on view_products  to doe;
```

Comment: the problem is that i can see the table with the user _doe_ or _lorem_ in for example sqldeveloper

Comment: What do you mean, "i can see the table?"  What are you expecting?

Comment: So, create a view, and grant access to the view.

Comment: I have to create a view from the user that created the table, or from the user that i want to see the table?