# ORA-01031: Insufficient privileges with view

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We have a problem with the following error: ORA-01031: Insufficient privileges

We use an Oracle 10 database.

We have created a .NET 4.7 API that queries an Oracle 10 database.
In this Oracle 10 database, we created 2 views

To date, our API performs the following queries:

1) Query a table to retrieve login information (email, password)
2) Query of 2 views.

Randomly, when our API queries views, we get the following message: ORA-01031: Insufficient privileges
From the first error message, we can no longer query our views because privileges are insufficient.

We can not determine the cause and what is really strange is that the case occurs randomly!

We need to reboot the IIS application pool to avoid the problem.

The user used to connect to the database is a user who has all rights.

An idea ?

Thank you for your feedback.

Have a good day.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is written in French. stackoverflow.com is an English-only web site; while there are other language-specific sites, I don't *think* there's a French one.

Comment: Ok for you ? :-)

Comment: This happens for views only? How are they created? Do they fetch data from the same schema they belong to, or do they access other schemas? Also, do they contain only columns or are there any functions involved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140643/ora-01031-insufficient-privileges-when-selecting-view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when selecting view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140643/ora-01031-insufficient-privileges-when-selecting-view)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The views are on the same schema.  In the colums, there are no fonctions. There are some founctions in the WHERE clause.